# Terraform getting stuck when running on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform with aws:

- Terraform `v0.14.8`
- provider `registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive` `v2.2.0`
- provider `registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws` `v3.55.0`

Current behavior:

- On my local machine it works fine.
- On local docker, that is used by Jenkins it's working fine
- On Jenkins with same docker on US-WEST-2 working fine
  but,
- On Jenkins with same docker on EU-CENTRAL-1 get stuck.
  In debug mode, I get:

> 2021-08-24T20:16:08.901Z [INFO]
> plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.55.0_x5: 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [DEBUG]
> [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Send Request lambda/GetLayerVersion failed,
> attempt 25/25, error RequestError: send request failed caused by: Get
> "https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2018-10-31/layers/awswrangler/versions/2":
> dial tcp 3.121.178.128:443: i/o timeout:
> timestamp=2021-08-24T20:16:08.901Z 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] vertex
> "module.key_rotation.aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_layer": visit
> complete 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] vertex
> "module.key_rotation.aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_layer": dynamic
> subgraph encountered errors 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] vertex
> "module.key_rotation.aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_layer": visit
> complete 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] vertex
> "module.key_rotation.aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_layer (expand)":
> dynamic subgraph encountered errors 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] vertex
> "module.key_rotation.aws_lambda_layer_version.lambda_layer (expand)":
> visit complete 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of
> "module.key_rotation.aws_lambda_function.sync_apps_db_lambda_function
> (expand)" errored, so skipping 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk:
> upstream of
> "module.key_rotation.aws_lambda_function.cleanup_lambda_function
> (expand)" errored, so skipping 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk:
> upstream of
> "module.key_rotation.aws_lambda_function.check_application_keys_lambda_function
> (expand)" errored, so skipping 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk:
> upstream of
> "module.key_rotation.aws_cloudwatch_event_target.event_target_lambda
> (expand)" errored, so skipping 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk:
> upstream of
> "module.key_rotation.aws_lambda_permission.allow_cloudwatch_to_call_cleaner_lambda
> (expand)" errored, so skipping 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk:
> upstream of
> "module.key_rotation.aws_lambda_permission.allow_cloudwatch_to_call_lambda
> (expand)" errored, so skipping 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk:
> upstream of
> "module.key_rotation.aws_cloudwatch_event_target.event_target_cleaner_lambda
> (expand)" errored, so skipping 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk:
> upstream of "module.key_rotation (close)" errored, so skipping
> 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of
> "provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"] (close)" errored,
> so skipping 2021/08/24 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of
> "meta.count-boundary (EachMode fixup)" errored, so skipping 2021/08/24
> 20:16:08 [TRACE] dag/walk: upstream of "root" errored, so skipping

Seems like it's related to lambda upload.

I tryied:

- update terraform to latest
- destroy everithing
- removing all the states also from S3

same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

As was stated in other response, the issue was:

> Get
> "https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2018-10-31/layers/awswrangler/versions/2":
> dial tcp 3.121.178.128:443: i/o timeout

the reason is lambda domain was missing on our proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause of your issue is this:

> Get "https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2018-10-31/layers/awswrangler/versions/2": dial tcp 3.121.178.128:443: i/o timeout

Why the `terraform` binary can't connect to the `eu-central-1` endpoint of the Lambda service is impossible to say based on the information you provided.

You don't say where or how Jenkins is deployed. I assume in some container on AWS?

It could be a temporary network glitch or for some reason connectivity to `eu-central-1` is blocked from your Jenkins deployment.

Have you retried after a few hours?

Are you able to reproduce this behaviour consistenly?

Comment: Yes, I'm running on a docker. This is consstent for the last week. I can run commands on eu-central-1 the terrafor is creating users and roles, but seems like it cant create the lambdas.

Comment: (You mean _as a docker container_)

I'm sorry but I'm out of options then :-)